# CTeX recent update causing problem: \ctex_gadd_hook:Nn \CJKhook { \ctex_set_ignorespaces: }

Tags: miktex-update, hooks, ctex

It was fine by 17th Sep and the file would compile using `PDFLaTeX` to produce PDF.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{ctexrep}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % uses graphicx
\usepackage[top=1.8cm,bottom=1.8cm,left=0.88cm,right=0.88cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\lipsum[4-10]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

But today, I updated my `MikTeX` and now it wouldn't compile...

Very hard to see and tell where it went wrong as I don't exactly use this syntax....

Must be somewhere in the package ...

Any suggestion ??

[image]

Comment: Please provide a complete but minimal example that others ought to be able to compile.

Comment: @daleif As I said in the post, it's not really "my" code, it's something in the package that has been updated. So I am not sure what kind of `MVE` would be useful...

Comment: Adding this to the preamble should work, but with pdfLaTeX I get another font error right ahead: `\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ctex_gadd_hook:Nn #1
  {
    \tl_if_exist:NF #1 { \tl_new:N #1 }
    \tl_gput_right:Nn #1
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: @daleif I have added a few more lines....

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Hmmmm, maybe the developers would fix it bug soon, if it is indeed a bug .... some of my other files run into similar problem when tried to compile (pdflatex)...

Comment: @CasperYC Yes, one of the CTeX developers already filed a bug in their repository: https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/542 so it should be fixed soon.  But I believe the fix will do roughly what the lines I sent above do.  Also, I removed the `expl3` and  `l3build` tags: although the code is written in `expl3`, it's not at all related.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I kinda of found that too. Waiting for the fix. Thanks.

Comment: hmmmmmmm still no fix.....

Comment: Part of the issue has been fixed in ctex-kit; the other part can be found in [https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/814](latex3/latex3#814). But both have not released a new version yet.

Comment: Adding the following codes ahead of \documentclass actually worked for me:

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \ctex_gadd_hook:Nn #1
  {
    \tl_new:N #1
    \tl_gput_right:Nn #1
  }
\exp_args:Nx \cctab_gset:Nn \c_document_cctab
  {
    \cctab_select:N \c_document_cctab
    \bool_lazy_or:nnF
      { \sys_if_engine_xetex_p: } { \sys_if_engine_luatex_p: }
      { \int_step_function:nnN { 128 } { 255 } \char_set_catcode_active:n }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

Comment: Texlive system updates ctex today, fixed the problem. The new version is dated Oct.19th.

Comment: @TroyWoo Thanks!

Comment: Still the same problem, they mention better to downgrade the version