# Undefined control sequence. \ctex_gadd_hook:Nn

Tags: errors, ctex

I am writing my Thesis and facing this problem. I am using MikTex with Texstudio. Tried to resolve the issue but failed to find the solution. I need your help.

Here is the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.170 \ctex_gadd_hook:Nn
                         \CJKhook { \ctex_set_ignorespaces: }
?
```

[image]

Comment: the bug has imho already been reported, but a fix isn't yet on ctan: https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/issues/542

Comment: @ Ulrike Fischer, Thank you for the comment, I am struggling, the time is short and the deadline is near.

Comment: well the changes in the commit are rather small, you could try to apply them to a local version https://github.com/CTeX-org/ctex-kit/commit/27cad49af453e643b3250c8f0320eee225086e4c

Comment: @Ghouri See my comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565455/ctex-recent-update-causing-problem-ctex-gadd-hooknn-cjkhook-ctex-set-igno#comment1424818_565455): add `\ExplSyntaxOn \cs_new_protected:Npn \ctex_gadd_hook:Nn #1 { \tl_if_exist:NF #1 { \tl_new:N #1 } \tl_gput_right:Nn #1 } \ExplSyntaxOff` at the top of your document.

Comment: @ Phelype Oleinik .. Thank you The problem solved 90 % the only error I can receive now is: Even I tried to compile with xelatex:    Emergency stop. \RequireXeTeX